# Nodejs/Express Generating Script Links

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How would I go about it to make my own custom script end point url?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('custom-script.js');
});

module.exports = router;
```

So lets say I have in the same directory a "custom-script.js"

I want to be able to call my endpoint url and get whatever script is inside that file.

This is pretty much like when you import Bootstrap JS into your page or Angular 1.0 onto your page with their cdn

Am I on the right path??

Comment: I read the question few times and I don't know what you want to do. What endpoint do you want to return what file? `/` to return `custom-script.js`? Then what problem do you have with your solution? Adding the expected behavior and your experienced behavior would help a lot.

Comment: @rsp Yeah the answer below answered my question. I just wanted to be able to get access to my script file by calling my endpoint url. It was actually easier than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to do, but the way I send files, is put them into a `public/` folder, and use this middleware

```
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

This makes all the files on the public folder accessible, so if you want to load `public/custom-script.js` you just go to http://localhost:PORT/custom-script.js, or on the html `<script src="/custom-script.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you. It was actually easier than I thought. I totally forgot you can just call it like that.